# Visibility Problem on Community Featured Topics Questions

Tags: community, napili, topics

I have a Napili Community setup with Featured Topics.  My portal users cannot see questions that anyone else posts to the Topics.  They can see their own posts.  I do not know what rights, sharing, etc. I need to change to make this work properly.  I have Customer Community licenses.  We do not have Knowledge.  I would appreciate guidance on this.

Comment: modify your user profiles or assign the permissions to users via a permission set. you can check [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_admin_feed_post_editing.htm&type=5) doc for what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work.  I needed to change the default sharing access for Users to Read for External Users.  It was set to private.

Comment: Glad you found the answer :thumbsup: